# xcopy regex for excluding names

Tags: cmd, xcopy

I have a folder named Account

I want to xcopy all its subfolders, but it two phases (i.e. two xcopy commands):

I want to splint this cmd:

> xcopy /I /E /Y %env.working_directory%\Deployment\Account\Release*.*
>   \file-srv\Archive\Products\Web\AccountsServices\Account.Toolbar\Nightly\Accounts_3.10_Merged\%system.build.number%

Account\folder1 in first xcopy

Account\ --> all other in second xcopy

How can I write the second xcopy? (regex for excluding "folder1")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(They are simple wildcards rather than regular expressions)

[Robocopy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145%28WS.10%29.aspx) ships with recent versions of windows & can do everything that xcopy can, it  supports `/xd` to exclude directories.

Comment: xcopy /I /E /Y  %env.working_directory%\Deployment\Account\Release\*.* \\file-srv\Archive\Products\Web\AccountsServices\Account.Toolbar\Nightly\Accounts_3.10_Merged\%system.build.number% /xd %env.working_directory%\Deployment\Account\Release\Toolbar\     ____________ this syntax is ok ?

Comment: /XD is for robocopy not xcopy so you want `robocopy "c:\sourcepath" "c:\destination" *.* /E /XD "dirnametoskip1" `